# How to open the browser in a raspberrypi from a python daemon?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, daemon

I have a Flask app that runs as a service (in systemd) in a raspberry pi. I want to open the web browser using the `webbrowser` module, but the app doesn't seem to be able to be access the graphic session. I've tried the following:

```py
import webbrowser as wb
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def test_wb():
   wb.Mozilla('firefox').open('https://www.youtube.com')
   return('Done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

But it just renders the `Done!` message without actually doing anything.
After the call to the `/test` endpoint, the log of the app from `systemctl status flask_app` only shows that the request was successfully responded (code 200).
I also tried running firefox with `run`, from `subprocess`, but the result is the same.

So my question is: Is there a way to run a graphical application from a python process that runs as a daemon in linux?

Comment: this may help - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/setting-display-in-systemd-service-file   I think it's do-able but top answer ends with "It's rather bizarre to start a GUI program from Systemd. It wasn't designed for this. GUI programs live in an X session, started by a user. Systemd is for system processes. You should experiment with daemons instead."

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the link I need.